# Error converting value "Firefox" to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.PineZorro.DebugAdapterType'

Tags: angular, debugging, firefox

I want to start Firefox instead Chrome for my Angular project. I have installed debug adapter from there https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug , it working fine.

Then I try to replace launch.json in Vs2022 and receive this error.

[image: Try to start firefox]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2022 debug adaptor supports only "chrome, edge, node" options.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqvIq.png

Example settings for chrome debugger :

```
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "launch Chrome debugger",
    "url": "https://localhost:3000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

More info :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2022

Comment: I don't like Microsoft and Google browser, because so many Google an Microsoft in my life. I use only FF because this is open source software https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects. And FF has perfectly debugger with perfectly remote control, for example from VS Code. So, How to force Microsoft VS 2022 accept FF debugger adapter as it doing VS Code?